# jQuery-validate per-element validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to set up some basic jQuery validation, but nothing seems to be working.  When I run the page and hit submit, the first textbox gets highlighted, but the message for the second textbox gets displayed in the summary.  If click in and out of the second textbox, both boxes get highlighted, but the message for the second box is displayed, twice.  Subsequently clicking the submit button causes the second message to display while the button is being pressed, but then hides when the button is released.

Clearly I've set something critical up incorrectly, but I can't for the life of me see what.

Form:

```
<form id="formInput">    
    Some Input  <input type="text" id="someInput1" />
    Some Input2 <input type="text" id="someInput2" />

    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" />    
</form>
```

Code (which is run from within the document.ready handler):

```
$('form').validate({
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).addClass("invalidElement");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass("invalidElement");
    },
    errorClass: "errorMsg",
    errorContainer: '#errorSummary',
    errorLabelContainer: '#errorsList',
    wrapper: 'li',
    onkeyup: false,
    focusCleanup: false
});

$("#someInput1").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: "Some input 1 is required"
    }
});

$("#someInput2").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    messages: {
        required: "Some input 2 is required"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code above is that the jQuery validation plugin requires all inputs to have names.

Adding

```
name="X" 
name="Y"
```

to the two text boxes fixed matters.

```
Some Input  <input type="text" name="X" class="someInput1" />
Some Input2 <input type="text" name="Y" class="someInput2" />
```

Comment: Oh just an FYI they don't *need* to be unique.  Radio groups for example share a `name`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're writing all that code because you eventually want to customize it more, but if you want your example to work in its most basic form all you need is this:

```
<form id="formInput">    
    Some Input  <input type="text" id="someInput1" class="required" />
    Some Input2 <input type="text" id="someInput2" class="required" />
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" />    
</form>

$('#formInput').validate();
```

At the very least, you could start with that and add *one* customised option at a time so you can see what's happening.

**Edit:** For custom messages (note I removed the inline rule via `class`):

```
<form id="formInput">    
    Some Input  <input type="text" id="someInput1" name="someinput1" />
    Some Input2 <input type="text" id="someInput2" name="someinput2" />
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" />    
</form>

$("#someInput1").rules("add", {
   required: true,
   messages: { required: "This input is required - learn2forminputn00b!!" }
});
```

**Alternate method (from docs):**

Using this method specifies rules and messages for those rules by form field `name` in the constructor.

```
$(".selector").validate({
   rules: {
     name: {
       required: true,
       minlength: 2
     }
   },
   messages: {
     name: {
       required: "We need your email address to contact you",
       minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required!")
     }
   }
})
```

Comment: I want the validation messages customized, which is why I was writing it that way  - is there an attribute I can add to achieve that?

Comment: Yup it's very simple, just clarify if you want the text of the message customized or the placement/style, etc. and I'll help you.  Don't say all of the above, start with one :)

Comment: I just want custom error messages - like above.  The default to-the-right placement is fine with me :)

Comment: Even commenting that custom stuff out, and adding required classes, this is still behaving weirdly - in much the same way as before (though without the custom messages).  There's definitely some deeper problem with my code.

Comment: Check out my edit, if you are really struggling and want even more features, make a jsFiddle and I'll help you with it.

Comment: No, I mean custom messages **per element**, not a custom message for all required elements.  From what I saw you're supposed to select the element you want a custom message for, then add the custom rule like I tried above

Comment: Oops, sorry just change the selector to the element you want that custom validator for.  Oh and I just noticed you aren't using `name` attributes, you need to add those because that's what the plugin looks at for custom rules.

Comment: That's exactly the same code I started with.  And it's not working in the way described in my question.

Comment: Except you added a whole bunch of global options in your original example.  Like I said, add one thing at a time.

Comment: The problem turned out to be jQ plugin needing unique names on all form inputs.  That fixed everything.  Thanks for trying to help with the above :)

Comment: Haha ya I noticed a bit late that you were missing those, sorry.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for, custom message per field by id, or in other words programmaticly. $("#someInput1").rules("add", {
   required: true,
   messages: { required: "This input is required - learn2forminputn00b!!" }
});